# JOOQ ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field is not contained in Row (1)

Tags: jooq

I am trying to evaluate JOOQ and I created the simple project in Eclipse based on the example provided here

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/using-java-object-oriented-querying-jooq-with-postgresql/?unapproved=249942&moderation-hash=6786f61e9b1af98c3dd59a50996bc603#comment-249942

I have successfully generated the classes when I am running the simple java program to retrieve  the data from database I am getting the following error here ( Main.java screen shot is attached)

```
Integer rank = r.getValue(LARGECITIES.RANK);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field (“jooq”.”largecities”.”rank”) is not contained in Row (1)
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.indexFail(Tools.java:1769)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:331)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.getValue(AbstractRecord.java:1250)
at org.jooq.jOOQTestpackage.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

However I have created the table largecities in the Public schema. “TEST” is the name of my database in Postgres.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You didn't attach that screenshot, but even better, can you just show the complete code you wrote here? What query is producing `r`?